# Mariadb client jar throwing ArrayIndexoutofbounds exception while deleting a row

Tags: hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am using mariadb as my ORM. I am deleting a row using primary key in a table using jpa. It is a simple native delete query. It looks that if matching row doesn't exists, the result set processing has this issue. The behavior is inconsistent though, not happening quite frequently.

`@Query(value ="Delete from table where id = :paramId",nativeQuery =true)`

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.Buffer.getLengthEncodedBytes(Buffer.java:318) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.ColumnInformation.getString(ColumnInformation.java:242) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.ColumnInformation.getName(ColumnInformation.java:258) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(MariaDbResultSetMetaData.java:187) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.hibernate.dialect.ColumnAliasExtractor$1.extractColumnAlias(ColumnAliasExtractor.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getColumnName(JdbcResultMetadata.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:487) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
```

Table structure:
CREATE TABLE `inst` (
`INST_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`STATUS_ID` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`MODULE_ID` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '2',
`STAGE_CONFIG_ID` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`COMMENTS` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`IS_LOCKED` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`LOCKED_BY` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`RECORD_DATE` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
`VERSION` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ROLE_ID` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`INST_ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `INST_PK` (`INST_ID`),
INDEX `INST_MODULE_FK` (`MODULE_ID`),
INDEX `INST_WKF_STAGE_CONFIG_FK1` (`STAGE_CONFIG_ID`),
INDEX `INST_ID` (`INST_ID`, `STAGE_CONFIG_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `INST_MODULE_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`MODULE_ID`) REFERENCES `module` (`MODULE_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `INST_WKF_STAGE_CONFIG_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`STAGE_CONFIG_ID`) REFERENCES `stage_config` (`STAGE_CONFIG_ID`)
)

Comment: Not sure this is the root cause because you get the exception only sometimes, but this should be a modifying query: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

Comment: strange, can you indicate mariadb server version and table 'table' DDL ?

Comment: @DiegoDupin, mariadb server version is 1.10.25.

Comment: @JensSchauder, thanks for the suggestion. I looked at Modifying annotation, is this effective when there is huge data to be processed in batches. My application is  db intensive.

Comment: @Diego Dupin, this issue is quite frequently happening now. do you suggest any connector update ? we are currently using 2.2.0. Thanks.

Comment: @Vjay did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Post upgrade to 2.3.0 the issue did not occur anymore.